# How to convert unix epoch time to readable format in perl

Tags: perl

How do I convert 1461241125.31307 in perl.  I tried:

```
use Date::Parse;
$unix_timestamp = '1461241125.31307';
my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime($unix_timestamp);
$mon += 1;
$year += 1900;
$unix_timestamp_normal = "$year-$mon-$mday $hour:$min:$sec";
```

result: `2016-4-21 5:18:45` (no padding of hour)

How do I pad it and make it GMT. I want the result to say `2016-04-21 12:18:45`

---

Thanks for the answers folks.

```
use DateTime;
$unix_timestamp = '1461241125.31307';
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $unix_timestamp);
print $dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),"\n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $epoch_ts = '1461241125.31307';

say strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime($epoch_ts));
```

Answer (score 8):

Easiest way:

```
print scalar localtime $unix_timestamp;
```

Documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html

For GMT, use `gmtime`:

```
print scalar gmtime $unix_timestamp;
```

Documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html (Basically says: Everything like `localtime`, but outputs GMT time.)

For custom formats, try `DateTime`:

```
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $unix_timestamp);
print $dt->strftime('%Y-%s');
```

See http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime for all options. Lots of formats could be created even more easily using the predefined DateTime Formatters: http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime%3A%3AFormat&mode=all

Comment: Using POSIX's strftime is much much more lightweight than using DateTime's (and it's core)

Answer (score 0):

Use `gmtime` instead of `localtime`

`perldoc -f gmtime` :

```
gmtime EXPR
gmtime  Works just like "localtime" but the returned values are localized
        for the standard Greenwich time zone.

        Note: When called in list context, $isdst, the last value returned
        by gmtime, is always 0. There is no Daylight Saving Time in GMT.

        Portability issues: "gmtime" in perlport.
```